# How can I get the CommonOpenFileDialog's InitialDirectory to be the user's MyDocuments path, instead of Libraries\Documents?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the CommonOpenFileDialog in the Windows API Code Pack as a folder picker dialog. I'm setting the InitialDirectory property to Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments). However, when I display the dialog, the path in the address bar is Libraries\Documents (not C:\users\craig\my documents as I'd expect). Additionally, if I just press the Select Folder button, I get a dialog saying that 'You've selected a library. Please choose a folder instead.'

Does someone know why my file path is being ignored, in favor of 'libraries\documents'? More importantly, how can I get the dialog to respect the InitialDirectory value I passed in?

The code I'm using for the dialog is:

```
if (CommonFileDialog.IsPlatformSupported)
{
    var folderSelectorDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    folderSelectorDialog.EnsureReadOnly = true;
    folderSelectorDialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
    folderSelectorDialog.AllowNonFileSystemItems = false;
    folderSelectorDialog.Multiselect = false;
    folderSelectorDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    folderSelectorDialog.Title = "Project Location";

    if (folderSelectorDialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
      ShellContainer shellContainer = null;

      try
      {
        // Try to get a valid selected item
        shellContainer = folderSelectorDialog.FileAsShellObject as ShellContainer;
      }
      catch
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not create a ShellObject from the selected item");
      }

      FilePath = shellContainer != null ? shellContainer.ParsingName : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

-Craig

Comment: What path do you get from "Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)"?

Comment: Libraries/Documents *is* your My Documents folder on Win7.  It works.

Comment: @Brent: The path you get is C:\users\Craig\My Documents, assuming Craig is your username

Comment: @Hans: I'm not disputing that Libraries\Documents points to My Documents. My problem is, as stated above, that attempting to select that folder as the initial directory produces a dialog box saying 'You've selected a library. Please choose a folder instead'. Hence why I want the dialog to display the file system path, as opposed to the library path.

Comment: On Win7 the folder won't be named "My Documents".  There's a hidden reparse point that redirects to Documents to keep legacy code working.  If you actually get "My Documents" from Environment.GetFolderPath() then the machine is messed up.

Comment: @Hans: You're right, it's actually C:\Users\Craig\Documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First of all, I'm sorry it took me so long to understand your question.*

The message I see is when I try this is:

> Cannot operate on
>   'Libraries\Documents' because it is
>   not part of the file system.

There's not much more to say.  A library is a virtual folder that is an amalgamation of various different real folders.

There's no real way to avoid this error. You have asked the dialog to return a folder and the user has not selected a folder. The dialog therefore cannot fulfil its part of the deal.

If you descend further into the folder structure, into real folders, then the dialog will return you a real value.

Comment: I'm not disputing the display of the friendly name. However, the dialog fails to translate the friendly name back to a file path, displaying the 'You've selected a library. Please choose a folder instead' dialog box. That's what I'm trying to avoid by having it use a file path instead of the library path.

Comment: @Craig Finally I think I understand your question!

Comment: @David: OK. So, if I can't prevent the initial directory from being converted to a library path, is there a way for me to translate a returned library path back to a file path, or catch it altogether? For example, let's say I change the dialog code so that AllowNonFileSystemItems is set to true. Then I run the dialog and select the 'Libraries' folder on the left side of the dialog and press the 'Select Folder' button. That will return a 'path' of ::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}. How can I detect that this isn't a file path so I can force the user to try again?

Comment: @Craig  A library is a virtual folder that is an amalgamation of various different real folders.  It's not a single folder.  If you select a file within a library, then you'll get back the real path.  But a virtual folder does not have a file system name.

Comment: @David: I understand that but that doesn't answer my question. As I pointed out, the dialog will return a string, regardless of whether I select a library or path. If I select a library, it returns the GUID I mentioned above. Is there a function I can pass that returned string to, that will confirm whether it's a file path or not?

Comment: @Craig OK, you can get the dialog to check this for you. I'm not familiar with the API Code Pack wrapper, but the native underlying dialog has an option flag called FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST. If you include that you'll get what you want handled automatically by the dialog. In your Code Pack wrapper I'd guess that there's a boolean property named PathMustExist. Set this to true.

Comment: @Craig Maybe it's called CheckPathExists.

Comment: The property is called EnsurePathExists. I gave it a shot but it didn't stop me from selecting a library as the folder path. At this point, I'd say don't worry about it. My question has definitely been answered - the dialog doesn't distinguish between file path and virtual paths (such as library guids) so I need to handle either case. Thanks again.

Comment: @Craig Try EnsureFileExists too. I can certainly get my dialogs to behave the way I describe, but I'm using IFileDialog from native code rather than your .net wrapper thereof.

Comment: @David: Will do. A solution I came up with is to use KnownFolderHelper.FromPath() to get a IKnownFolder object for the selected path string. I then use 

    if (knownFolder is NonFileSystemKnownFolder) 

to test if the path is not a file system path.

Comment: @Craig Keep trying with the dialog. It will definitely yield with the right settings. The text I quoted in my updated answer comes from the dialog when it refuses to close for this reason. If you can't crack it, leave me a comment here and I'll help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
folderSelectorDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

try

```
folderSelectorDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) MyDocuments and Personal are equivalent.

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately, it also produced the 'You've select a library...' dialog.